# Find n such that $(n - 1)! - (n - 2)! + (n - 3)! - (n - 4)! + \cdots$ modulo $n$ = 2.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

An alternating factorial is the absolute value of the alternating sum of the first n factorials of positive integers.
To put it algebraically,

$$\mathrm{af}(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^{n - i}i!.$$

Now, we consider n such that $\mathrm{af}(n - 1) $ modulo $n$ = 2.

I find $\mathrm{af}(1108) $ modulo $1109$ = 2.

Are there another integers such that $\mathrm{af}(n - 1) $ modulo $n$ = 2?

Comment: I have run my program to `40000` (my computer's limit) and `1109` is still the only solution.

Comment: @Kenny Lau I have run my program to 100000 and 1109 is still the only solution.(http://manchanr6.blogspot.jp/2016/04/1604032.html)

Comment: I memoized my program, so maybe I could sacrifice time for more memory.

Comment: I am now running from 100001 to 200000.

Comment: [Just for reference](http://oeis.org/A005165)

Comment: Nothing in that range. This function, as seen in the reference, is not so understood. There is a lot of mystery around that function.

Comment: Just terminated. Nothing in that range. I am not going to go through any more range for obvious reasons.

Comment: I have also run a program t try to find solutions. There are no solutions up to $10^6$, and any solutions smaller than $10^{12}$ must be prime.

Comment: (When I say no solution up to $10^6$, I of course mean no solutions other than $1109$. I have now checked up to $1750000$.)