# Is there an $n$ such as $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k * k! \equiv 1\mod n$ other than the divisors of 246?

Tags: number-theory

$-1! \equiv 1\mod  1$.

$-1! + 2! \equiv 1\mod  2$.

$-1! + 2! - 3!\equiv -5 \equiv  1\mod 3$.

$-1! + 2! - 3! + 4! - 5! + 6! \equiv 619\equiv 1 \mod 6$.

Let $S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k * k!.$

When $n = 1, 2, 3, 6, 41, 82, 123$ and $246$, $S(n)\equiv 1\mod n$.

Is there an n such as $S(n) \equiv 1\mod n$ other than the divisors of 246?

Comment: Not if $n<100,000$.

Comment: This is similar to problem B43 in Richard K. Guy's Unsolved Problems in Number Theory. There it's conjectured that only $n$ such that $S(n)\equiv -1 \pmod n$ are divisors of $4454060$ (see also https://oeis.org/A064383).

Comment: Also similar to this previous question of yours: [Find n such that $(n - 1)! - (n - 2)! + (n - 3)! - (n - 4)! + \cdots$ modulo $n$ = 2.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725875)